# Change the Elementor menu dropdown animation

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I want to change the default dropdown menu animation. To be honest, default dropdown menu animation on mobile is exact what I want. How can I duplicate it on desktop?

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand correctly: Do you want to create a full-width dropdown menu?

1. Create a pop-up that will function as your menu by adding a navigation widget. After designing it, go ahead and also configure the popup settings as needed. Make sure you select "slide down" for the dropdown effect.
2. Add an "X" icon with fixed positioning that you can use for closing the popup. With the icon selected click on "link" and select "close popup".
3. On your homepage and all other pages that apply add your hamburger menu icon (usually 3 horizontal lines) and use fixed positioning – I assume you will want to use top:0 and right: 0; for it to be in the top right corner.
4. With the icon selected click on "link", select "open popup" and choose the popup you just created. (You may have to type the first couple of letters for it to show up)

[image: Have a look at this screenshot of the icon settings]

Hope this helps!